# Couchbase - Where to download the beer-sample bucket documents?

Tags: couchbase

I deleted the Couchbase beer-sample bucket recently. Where can I get the bucket with its documents to test the codes on [couchbase-node](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/beersample-node)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.  That was accounted for in support of sample buckets.  In the console, under settings there is a section called sample buckets.  Check the box next to the beer-sample and click "Create".

[image: screenshot of Sample Buckets setting in 4.0.0-rc0]

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, [you can reinstall it](http://blog.couchbase.com/ive-installed-couchbase-server-20-now-what) if the app is still working, but I suspect it comes from your local directories (maybe not!):

> As shown in Figure 2, if you have installed the beer-sample bucket, you will notice that this sample bucket has 7303 documents. If you haven’t installed the beer-sample bucket yet, you can still install it through the admin console - go to the ‘Settings’ tab, click on ‘Sample Buckets’ and select ‘beer-sample’ to install it.

If that doesn't work, I think your best bet is going to be to reinstall the app. You might be able to pick apart [an install .rpm](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads), but that doesn't seem worth it. You could install on a VM and copy the missing files over if that's convenient. But again, reinstall is quick if you don't have other stuff already running on Couchbase.